# JSON Parse [ and ]

Tags: .net, json, vb.net

I have JSON data from URL and I need split values,

```
"name":"michael",
"number":"0015454545",
"age":"22",
"interest":[
    ["swim","baseball","music","tenis"],
    ["washington","3","27","a"],
    ["New york","2","16","b"],
    ["los angeles","21","11","c"],
    ["dallas","7","22","a"]
]
```

My code:

```
Dim json As String = MyjsonDataLink
Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
Dim data As List(Of JToken) = ser.Children().ToList

For Each item As JProperty In data
    item.CreateReader()
    If item.Name = "interest" Then
        Response.Write(item.Value.ToString)
        Response.Write("<br><br><br>")
    Next
    End If
Next
```

But, text output is,

```
["washington","3","27","a"],
["new york","2","16","b"],
["los angeles","21","11","c"],
["dallas","7","22","a"]]
```

How do I extract the "washington", "new york", "los angeles", and "dallas" strings?

Comment: Are you sure that's what's printing? Because I would have expected to see the `["swim","baseball","music","edit"],` line in there, without the ending `]`...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan- looks like the copy and paste screwed up.  The op has `Next` and `End If` out of order...

Comment: i need parse "[" to "]" value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ was built for situations like this.  Here's a console app illustrating:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    'ignore the <a> tag, it's just a trick for multi-line strings
    Dim json = <a>
{"name":"michael",
"number":"0015454545",
"age":"22",
"interest":[
    ["swim","baseball","music","tenis"],
    ["washington","3","27","a"],
    ["New york","2","16","b"],
    ["los angeles","21","11","c"],
    ["dallas","7","22","a"]
]}</a>.Value
    Dim ser As JObject = JObject.Parse(json)
    'now let LINQ do the work for us
    Dim output = From s In ser("interest").Children Select s.First
    For Each item In output
      Console.Write(item)
      Console.Write("<br/><br/><br/>")
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub
End Module
```

Result:

```
swim<br/><br/><br/>washington<br/><br/><br/>New york<br/><br/><br/>los angeles<br/><br/><br/>dallas<br/><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Here's some great Json.Net LINQ info (in C#): http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm